# GO GORM .Related() construct not working with non-default primary key names.

Tags: go, go-gorm

When using the "default" primary key naming convention:

POSTGRES tables

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id SERIAL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE email
(
    id SERIAL,
    person_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
    CONSTRAINT email_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This .Related() construct works fine per the examples:

```
type Person struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    Emails   []Email
}

type Email struct {
    ID       int
    PersonID int
}
person := models.Person{}
conn.DB.First(&person).Related(&person.Emails)
```

But when using non-default primary keys names, the example does not work. Only one email is added to Emails regardless of how many there are.

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    person_id SERIAL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
)

CREATE TABLE email
(
    email_id SERIAL,
    person_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES person(person_id),
    CONSTRAINT email_pk PRIMARY KEY (email_id)
)


type Person struct {
    PersonId int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string
    Emails   []Email `gorm:"ForeignKey:PersonId"`
}

type Email struct {
    EmailId  int    `gorm:"primary_key"`
    PersonId int
}

person := models.Person{}
conn.DB.First(&person).Related(&person.Emails)
```

I've had to resort to using this construct:

```
person := models.Person{}
conn.DB.First(&person)
conn.DB.Where("person_id = ?", person.PersonId).Find(&person.Emails)
```

Is it possible to make .Related() work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Here are the corrected structs:

```
type Person struct {
    PersonId int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string
    Emails   []Email `gorm:"ForeignKey:PersonRefer"`
}

type Email struct {
    EmailId     int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Person      Person
    PersonRefer int `gorm:"column:person_id"`
}

conn.DB.First(&person).Related(&person.Emails, "PersonRefer")
```